# How to deploy App Service + Certificate + hostbinding at the same time with bicep?

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm having trouble deployed an hostNameBinding with a certificate at the same time with this code:

```
param appserviceplanId string
param location string
param appservicename string
param domain string

resource appservice 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {
  name: appservicename
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appserviceplanId
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      webSocketsEnabled: true
      alwaysOn: true
      http20Enabled: true
      autoHealEnabled: true
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v5.0'
    }
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
  }
}

resource certificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2021-01-01' = {
  name: '${domain}-certificate'
  location: location
  properties: {
    canonicalName: domain
    serverFarmId: appserviceplanId
    domainValidationMethod: 'http-token'
  }
}

resource hostbinding 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2021-01-01' = {
  parent: appservice
  name: domain
  properties: {
    siteName: appservicename
    customHostNameDnsRecordType: 'CName'
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    thumbprint: certificate.properties.thumbprint
  }
}
```

It only works if i deploy it in steps by commenting out the certificate:

```
param appserviceplanId string
param location string
param appservicename string
param domain string

resource appservice 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {
  name: appservicename
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appserviceplanId
    customDomainVerificationId: 'DNS Record verification'
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      webSocketsEnabled: true
      alwaysOn: true
      http20Enabled: true
      autoHealEnabled: true
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v5.0'
    }
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
  }
}

// resource certificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2021-01-01' = {
//   name: '${domain}-certificate'
//   location: location
//   properties: {
//     canonicalName: domain
//     serverFarmId: appserviceplanId
//     domainValidationMethod: 'http-token'
//   }
// }

resource hostbinding 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2021-01-01' = {
  parent: appservice
  name: domain
  properties: {
    siteName: appservicename
    customHostNameDnsRecordType: 'CName'
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    // sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    // thumbprint: certificate.properties.thumbprint
  }
}
```

After this i can run the whole thing because the Hostbinding exists.

How can i make it go in one go?

So, the Hostbinding cant be made without certificate, the certificate cant be made without a hostbinding, loop di loop.

If i specify the HostBinding before the certificate resource and then again after the certificate with the properties, i get 'HostName is specified more then once'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use module.

There's example with function app: https://github.com/Azure/bicep/tree/main/src/Bicep.Core.Samples/Files/user_submitted/301/function-app-with-custom-domain-managed-certificate

([perma link](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/blob/5cdd97d13791e81ca672f27aafd3929bcb3b4cb0/src/Bicep.Core.Samples/Files/user_submitted/301/function-app-with-custom-domain-managed-certificate/main.bicep#L1))

Comment: An example would be great, the specified resource no longer exists.

Comment: I’ve updated the url

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to set up a custom domain for a webapp, including certificate and DNS.
As done in @Miq's link, the host-binding needs to be set up in two steps, first with SSL disabled and then later with it enabled.

Steps:

1. Create DNS TXT/CNAME records
2. Create hostbinding with SSL disabled
3. Create certificate (this requires the hostbinding)
4. Enable SSL/SNI for the hostbinding in a separate module

We need the separate module so we can "delay" updating the same resource (host-binding) via the `dependsOn`, i.e. after the dependant resource is created (the certificate).

```
// Main.bicep

var domain = 'mydomain.com'
var subdomain = 'xyz'
var endpoint = '${subdomain}.${domain}'

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: 'myAppServicePlan'
}

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: 'myWebApp'
}

module dns 'DNS.bicep' = {
  name: 'dns'
  params: {
    cname: webApp.properties.defaultHostName
    subdomain: subdomain
    thumbprint: webApp.properties.customDomainVerificationId
    domain: domain
  }
}

resource hostBinding 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2022-09-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: endpoint
  dependsOn: [
    dns
  ]
  properties: {
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    sslState: 'Disabled'
    customHostNameDnsRecordType: 'CName'
    siteName: webApp.name
  }
}

resource certificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2022-09-01' = {
  name: '${endpoint}-certificate'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  dependsOn: [
    hostBinding
  ]
  properties: any({
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    canonicalName: endpoint
  })
}

module hostEnable 'SNI.bicep' = {
  name: 'enableSNI'
  dependsOn: [
    dns
  ]
  params: {
    appHostname: endpoint
    appName: webApp.name
    certificateThumbprint: certificate.properties.thumbprint
  }
}
```

```
// DNS.bicep

param domain string // e.g. domain.com
param subdomain string // e.g. xyz (in xyz.domain.com)
param cname string // e.g. xyz-my-domain.azurewebsites.net
param thumbprint string

resource dnsZone 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2018-05-01' existing = {
  name: domain
}

resource cnameRecord 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME@2018-05-01' = {
  parent: dnsZone
  name: subdomain
  properties: {
    TTL: 3600
    CNAMERecord: {
      cname: cname
    }
  }
}

resource txtRecord 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/TXT@2018-05-01' = {
  parent: dnsZone
  name: 'asuid.${subdomain}'
  properties: {
    TTL: 3600
    TXTRecords: [
      {
        value: [
          thumbprint
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// SNI.bicep

param appName string // from webApp.name
param appHostname string // the full endpoint for this web app (xyz.domain.com)
param certificateThumbprint string // from certificate.properties.thumbprint

resource hostBinding 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2020-06-01' = {
  name: '${appName}/${appHostname}'
  properties: {
    sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    thumbprint: certificateThumbprint
  }
}
```