# Azure bicep: Creating certificate gives "Endpoint not found"

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create a custom domain for a microservice:

- portal.dev.mydomain.com *(mydomain.com is a placeholder here)*

I create certificate/host-bindings in bicep with this:

```
var portalEndpoint = 'portal.${domain}'

resource portalCertificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2022-09-01' = {
  name: '${portalEndpoint}-certificate'
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    domainValidationMethod: 'http-token'
  }
}

resource portalHostBinding 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2022-09-01' = {
  parent: portalWebApp
  name: portalEndpoint
  properties: {
    siteName: portalWebAppName
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    thumbprint: portalCertificate.properties.thumbprint
  }
}
```

I execute the deployment with this:

```
az deployment group create `
    --resource-group [my-resource-group] `
    --template-file /path/to/bicep/file
```

For the certificate it gives a nasty HTML page as error (I cut out the CSS to make it shorter):

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "target": "/subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/REDACTED.Resources",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "NotFound",
                "target": "/subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/portal.dev.REDACTED.com-certificate",
                "message": "{\r\n  \"Code\": \"NotFound\",\r\n  \"Message\": \"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"utf-8\\\"?>\\r\\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\\\" \\\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\\\">\\r\\n<html xmlns=\\\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\\\">\\r\\n  <head>\\r\\n    <title>Service</title>\\r\\n    \\r\\n  </head>\\r\\n  <body>\\r\\n    <div id=\\\"content\\\">\\r\\n      <p class=\\\"heading1\\\">Service</p>\\r\\n      <p xmlns=\\\"\\\">Endpoint not found. Please see the <a rel=\\\"help-page\\\" href=\\\"https://waws-prod-db3-305.api.azurewebsites.windows.net:454/subscriptions/help\\\">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>\\r\\n    </div>\\r\\n  </body>\\r\\n</html>\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Innererror\": null\r\n}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand the error or prerequisites for the resources?

I'm also adding TXT/CNAME DNS records in a separate step, and this too succeeds for the identity-domain.

Essentially, I'm trying to perform the same steps as adding a custom domain in portal (add custom domain, set up DNS TXT/CNAME records, verify).

Comment: Can you try adding `dependsOn:[ portalCertificate ]` under `portalHostBinding` resource to add dependency and deploy again? @Jeppe

Comment: @Jahnavi same error. I also get it even if I leave out the hostBinding resource. So it seems to be the certificate resource (also mentioned in the error).

Comment: It turns out I had a leftover certificate for the identity-domain, which is why that didn't fail. Now that I've removed it, both certificates fails. I think I need to make sure the custom-domain (hostbinding?) exists before the certificate is added.. Probably that is the endpoint it is complaining about.

Comment: Yes the custom domain has to be existed before the certificate addition. @Jeppe

Comment: Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938529/how-to-deploy-app-service-certificate-hostbinding-at-the-same-time-with-bice) for relevant information. Is this works for you? @Jeppe

Comment: @Jahnavi That was it! As mentioned in that answer, it is a two-step procedure. Should I mark this as a duplicate or answer it?

Comment: I will provide an answer with detailed steps so that it will be helpful for community as well. @Jeppe

Comment: @Jahnavi I created an answer as well with the final code. Thank you for your help!